# Apache Camel Content Based Routing on Websocket Connections

Tags: apache-camel, java-websocket

I have a hypothetical scenario:  let’s pretend I have an Apache Camel websocket server and I’m allowing many websocket connections.  Each client connection will need to be associated with a ClientID.  The ClientID is obtained by a new connection via an InitConnection json message where a ClientID is a member of the message.  The question is:  is it possible to have camel associate a websocket instance with a ClientID in order to perform content based routing?

Comment: Do you mean camel performs adding call to the json message that contains the clientid?

Comment: No. I'd like to have camel pull the clientId from the message.  Look up the websocket from a recipientList by the clientId.

Comment: That should be done with a choice() and when(). But yeah should work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, It is possible. you can retrieve a UUID of each client by below method:

```
from("direct:Consumer1")
    .process(new Processor() {
     public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
       Map<String, Object> headers=exchange.getIn().getHeaders();
    //you can get a unique connection key from the exchange header.
    //store this key somewhere, to send messages to particular client.
    String uniqueConnectionKey=headers.get("websocket.connectionKey").toString();
          //you can get message from the client like below.
          String dataFromClient=exchange.getIn().getBody().toString();

   }
}).end();
```

you need to map this unique key with ur client id, so that u can send messages to particular client using this UUID.

```
 CamelContext camelContext=new DefaultCamelContext();
   ProducerTemplate template=camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
   template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:Producer1", {message}, "connectionKey",    {connectionkey});
```

direct:Producer1 : producer endpoint name.

connectionkey : a unique connection key, which you will get from the exchange header in websocket consumer.

message : message to the websocket endpoint.

Edit :
here is the producer route.

```
from("direct:Producer1").
      //we will use this connectionKey for uniquely identifying each connection from the client.
      setHeader(WebsocketConstants.CONNECTION_KEY, header("connectionKey")).
      to("websocket://{host}:{port}/camel-websocket?sendToAll=false").end();
```

Comment: Can you please explain,  how to and where to store the connection key from the Producer, to send messages to particular client.

Comment: @PrinceyJames  you can store the connection key in a static hash map.if your connection is bound to a process or user you can use its id as key and connection key as value. when your client closes the connection, you should remove the connection key from this map.

Comment: in my case, each connection is bound to a process. before starting the process, client will make a websocket connection with the server using process id, server keeps this unique connection key with process id in a map and sends the status of process using process id and connection key.