# Using Apache Camel with multiple websocket endpoints

Tags: java, websocket, apache-camel

I have a Jetty endpoint receiving push-messages of different types from several data-providers - let´s call them *type1*, *type2*.

I also provide set of websocket-endpoints - one for each type -  where clients can subscribe to push-updates of the different message-types (/ws_type1, /ws_type2).

The dataproviders and the clients are not the same.

Based on the type of incoming message, I am trying to get the camel route to push updates only to the clients subscribing to the specific messagetype.

My code is something like this:

```
    from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8888/incoming_1?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
            .log("incoming_1")
            .to("websocket://ws_type1?sendToAll=true");

    from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8888/incoming_2?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
            .log("incoming_2")
            .to("websocket://ws_type2?sendToAll=true");

    from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/incoming?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
            .log("incoming")
            .to("websocket://woot?sendToAll=true");

    from("websocket://ws_type1")
            .log("ws_type1")
            .to("websocket://ws_type1")
    ;
    from("websocket://ws_type2")
            .log("ws_type2")
            .to("websocket://ws_type2")
    ;
```

The result of this is that *ALL* messages of *ALL* types are sent to *ALL* the connected clients - regardless if they are connected to the **/ws_type1** or **/ws_type2** endpoints.

Is it possible to filter the updates to different sets of clients? I.e. messages of *type1* are pushed to the clients connected to **/ws_type1**, and messages of *type2* are pushed to the clients connected to **/ws_type2**.

**EDIT:**
Using the code above, I am able to connect websockets to ws-endpoints "ws_type1", "ws_type2", and "woot". However - when I post data to the "/incoming_1" jetty-endpoint ALL three websockets receive the data, but only "incoming_1" is logged.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT 2:**
I looked at the camel-websocket source, and it seems like this is by design. There is no filtering on which websockets the message-contents are sent to, and the content is written directly to the socket. This also means that the camel-routes "ws_type1" and "ws_type2" in the example above will not be called when the server pushes data.

```
    ....
    Collection<DefaultWebsocket> websockets = store.getAll();
    Exception exception = null;
    for (DefaultWebsocket websocket : websockets) {
        try {
            sendMessage(websocket, message);
    ...
```

[Full source](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-websocket/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/websocket/WebsocketProducer.java#L87-L91)

Comment: So is the choice() not working as you expect? If you add log() within each do both log a message?

Comment: The choice()-part works as it is supposed - I have altered the example to avoid confusion. Also - none of the log()-statements within each websocket are called.

Comment: Please check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485523/apache-camel-content-based-routing-on-websocket-connections/ Hope this would help you